# Mocking method in abstract Controller with phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I want to mock a method with PHPunit in Zend Framework 2.

The method is part of a 'AbstractController' class which is extended by the class I am testing.

The code I use to test:

```
 public function testAddPostAction()
{
    $this->mockBjy();
    $this->mockZFC();

    $zfcUser = $this->getMockBuilder('Common\Controller\AbstractController')->getMock();
    $zfcUser ->method('getUserId')
            ->will($this->returnValue('2'));
      $this->assertEquals(2, $zfcUser->getUserId());

    $this->dispatch('/leaverequest/add','POST', array('user' => '2','reasonforleave' => 'PHPunit','leaveRequestDates'=> '05/06/2015 - 05/15/2015'));
    $this->assertModuleName('Employment');
    $this->assertControllerName('employment\controller\leaverequest');
    $this->assertControllerClass('LeaveRequestController');
    $this->assertActionName('add');
    $this->assertMatchedRouteName('leaverequest/add');
}
```

The code in the abstract Controller:

```
protected function getUserId()
{
    return $this->zfcUserAuthentication()
                    ->getIdentity()
                    ->getId();
}
```

The code in the controller being tested that requires this method, look at the 2nd parameter in the method being called on the second line of the if statement ($this->getUserId()).

```
public function addAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $this->getServiceLocator()->get('leaveRequestService')->addLeaveRequest($this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(), $this->getUserId());
        $returnValue = $this->redirect()->toRoute('leaverequest/list');
    } else {
        $users = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('userService')->findAllUsers();
        $returnValue = new ViewModel(array('users' => $users));
    }
    return $returnValue;
}
```

I would need the mock the result of this method, but am unable to do so with the current code. The message I receive is as follows: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in .....

Thank you in advance :)

---

So I have realised that mocking the abstract was a bad approach and should rather mock the leave request service called by the dispatch method. I have now tried to mock the leave request addLeaveRequestService, but the second parameter $this->getUserId is still being triggered causing the unit test to go the the getId method in the abstract controller where it fails and provides the error message "
"call to member function on a non-object"

Comment: You don't set the mocked object on the service locator used in the `dispatch` call. Also I don't understand why you want to mock the abstract controller and not the one that `dispatch` will end up using. Have you read the [zf2 user guide section about mocking services in controller tests](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#configuring-the-service-manager-for-the-tests)? It's quite neat and all that stuff is covered there.

Comment: Dispatch ends up using $this->getUserId, $this refers to the abstractController which is extended by the class I am testing. I cannot treat an abstractController as a service from what I understand. Please do correct me if otherwise. I am looking at the documentation but I am not reaching a solution.